# Duplicate entry 'n' for key 'primary', change ID when is duplicate

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I have a MySQL table with a `ID`column set as `auto_increment`. The table already contains some values.

I need to import about 4000 new rows that in some case they have the same ID that already exist on the table, so MySQL returns this error:

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'

How can I deal with it?

Below I post a piece of code that concern the file that I need to import:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts`
     (`ID`,`post_author`,`post_date`,`post_date_gmt`,`post_content`,`post_title`,`post_excerpt`,`post_status`,...)
  VALUES
     (7,1,'2015-04-24 11:19:41'....);
```

[and so on for 4000 rows ]

What I need is that the ID value is the same changes automatically.

Comment: If IDs are relevant you shouldn't force the insertion (you'll have actual duplicates). If they are not, you shouldn't specify any ID at all and let MySQL take care of that.

Comment: Could you manually update the id values in the imported script? Another approach could be to import the values in another table, and then perform two `insert into select` statements, one for existing ids and one for non existing ids.

Comment: Manually is hard work, the duplicate key are more that 1000. Thank you for the response. I'll try new solutions

Comment: Could you change all ids in the import script for example by adding a high number?

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to update existing rows when the IDs match, try adding an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts (ID, post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content,
                      post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, ...)
VALUES (7, 1, '2015-04-24 11:19:41', ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    post_author=VALUES(post_author), post_date=VALUES(post_date),
    post_date_gmt=VALUES(post_date_gmt), post_content=VALUES(post_content),
    post_title=VALUES(post_title), post_excerpt=VALUES(post_excerpt),
    post_status=VALUES(post_status), ...
```

Comment: Thanks reaanb. It's what I'm looking for.
So I can add 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=null' and my ID automatically  auto-increment? My Problem now is if I can affect this statment on all the rows without add it on all 4000 lines.

Comment: No, as it says: "on duplicate key update", (i.e. it will not insert, but update), it will set the id column to the value 0. "If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that your `ID` field is `autoincrement`. 
So you don't need to force `id` column during insertion. your insert query will `autogenerate` non duplicate unique id's

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_title,post_excerpt,post_status,...) VALUES (1,'2015-04-24 11:19:41'....)
```

Comment: Yes User, but my ploblem is that I have this auto-generated file with 4000 rows that have the ID already set. I think I will use on duplicate key

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your concern, you might use:

```
INSERT INTO wp_post (ID,post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_title,post_excerpt,post_status,...) VALUES (7,1,'2015-04-24 11:19:41'....) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = 0;
```

and check if id has auto_increment attribute.